# Read binary files directly with python to use fo statistical analysis

Tags: python, binary, byte

I am trying to read binary file directly with python without converting it to ascii or text format.

I already have ascii converted data from this binary file, but the analysis results seem bit questionable.

So, I would like to use this binary file itself for the analysis.

In my previous question, I even didn't know the format of my file. So, I tried to check it with od -xc function.

The part of my binary data look like below:

```
12335640    003c    0400    0060    0000    0000    fc1a    0b61    0016
          <  \0  \0 004   `  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 032   ?  a  \v 026  \0
12335660    c000    040f    c000    040f    0000    0000    0000    0000
          \0   ?017 004  \0   ?017 004  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
12335700    01ea    0fab    07dd    0e07    1c15    07dd    0e07    1c15
          ?001   ?017   ? \a  \a 016 025 034   ? \a  \a 016 025 034
```

I am not very familiar with a binary format, but this format looks mostly 4-byte except first column.

I tried to use binascii module as in previous question, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

The code which I used in the previous question was:

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
f = open(filin,'r')
for c in range(0,19):
    a = []
    for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in f):
        a.append(columns[c])
        print a
        x = str(a).strip('[]')
        print x
        y = binascii.b2a_uu(x)
        print y
```

Thank you,

Issac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be want to use the `numpy`module to read your file into a numpy.array.

For example:

```
import numpy

print numpy.fromstring('abcd', dtype='u1')
# 8-bit unsigned int: [97,97,97,97]

print numpy.fromstring('abcd', dtype='i2')
# 16-bit signed int [25185, 25699]

print numpy.fromstring('abcd', dtype='<f4')
# 32-bit float (little-endian): 1.67779994e+22

print numpy.fromstring('abcd', ftype='>f4')
# 32-bit float (big-endian): 2.61007876e+20
```

This works with almost any data files with constant record structure. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html for more complicated examples of `numpy.fromfile`. If your binary file has constant records, you can load them with a single command into an easy-to-use array for more maths.

Comment: Good suggestion. As in my example above, this only works with a perfectly homogeneous data set. It's crucial that @Isaac figures out the structure of the data first.

Comment: @Dan I agree. Constant record structure is required. Of course it may help, if you know all your data is 16 bit ints or something else, but if you know nothing, pure octets are the best bet. Then data type 'u1' helps with the statistics, but byte arrays are almost as useful. (BTW, if you really like my suggestion, you know what to click :)

Comment: Thank you Dan and DrV, I have tried methods from both of you. However, the results didn't seem what I expected and what should be in the data, even though I used all of methods. It might be because datatypes which I used were not correct. I will try other data type. Thank you again, Isaac

Comment: @Isaac, I strongly suggest that you stop worrying about how to read the data until you have figured out the format of the data. Where did the original files come from? Can you ask the author to explain the format for you, or look at the source code of the program that produced them, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

As with your previous question, this data could represent **anything**. It could be [big-endian](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/endianness) floating point values, it could be little-endian integers, etc. etc. You might be able to make an educated guess at the format by looking for some commonly-repeating values or locations of known values, but this will be very error-prone.

If, **hypothetically**, the data is simply a stream of 4-byte single-precision floating-point numbers with native endianness, then you can read them using the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) which decodes binary data from C-like structures into Python types.

```
from struct import unpack
f = open(fn, 'rb') # don't forget the b, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
output_list = []

while True:
    chunk = f.read(4)
    if len(chunk)<4:
        break
    value = unpack("f", chunk)
    output_list.append(value)
```

... after all that you should have a list of floating-point values.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I apologize late answer. I added my comment on DrV's answer.